# Json response not displaying a success message in the view (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to return the following message via Json as shown below. The $message is showing in the Response, but not sure how to display it in the view. I tried the below attempt, but failed.
Also If I don't use `location.reload();` , the edit done will not show without reloading the page. So how can I do this properly?

Controller :

```
$message = "Successfully edited!";
return response()->json(['new_body' => $greq->title, 'message' => $message], 200);
```

JS :

```
.done(function () {
             // location.reload();
             $('#message').text(msg['message']);
             $('#edit-greq').modal('hide');
        });
```

View :

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
<div class="alert alert-success" align="center" id="message">
  <strong>{{Session::get('message')}}</strong>
</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS

```
.done(function (msg) { // You need to add return variable
        $('#message').text(msg['message']); // In order to make it show you need to have this HTML element
        $('#edit-greq').modal('hide');
});
```

View

```
<div class="alert alert-success" align="center" id="message">
    @if(Session::has('message'))
        <strong>{{Session::get('message')}}</strong>
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: But why its not working when I put the if condition outside the Div ?

Comment: When I put it inside, there will be a trace of the Div in green color before even editting, which is not looking good.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to fix it ?

Comment: It's because when you put outside of div, this div will not be created if you don't have message session, the green color is the element css, to ease the work, you can play hide and show, eg: class="alert alert-success hide", then when .done, add this javascript, $('#message').removeClass('hide')